# Firebase not displaying css properly

Tags: html, css, firebase, firebase-hosting

i'm working on a college project and my coding skills aren't the greatest. I've created a Firebase project to host a temporary website. The website is going to be developed using bootstrap. When i connect to the site after it has been deployed there is no styling present at all. However when i run the same index.html & CSS code on codeply or jsbin it appears exactly how i want it to. Can anyone think of anything that might be causing the issue? It's been wrecking my head for a very long week! Any pointers would be great.
Here is a link to my git with the latest code: https://github.com/Realcolm/New-Gers-Garage/tree/Update-CSS

Comment: `cntrl + shift + i` then right click the reload icon and choose "Empty Cache And Hard Reload"

Answer (score 16):

This is due to the browser caching your styles. To fix it just use a hard refresh on the browser you are using. Ctrl and ⇧ Shift and then press R for windows on chrome and ⌘ Cmd and ⇧ Shift and then press R on mac.

Answer (score 5):

Your `public` directory in `firebase.json` is the root directory for a Firebase Hosting deploy. Only files that are within that directory will be deployed and available.

Your CSS files are in your top-level project directory, and so are likely not getting deployed. You should move all of your HTML/CSS/JS inside the `public` directory.